# Is it bad practice to use the null-forgiving operator with `useRef`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

Would the following be considered bad practice?

```
const Component: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null!);

    return <div ref={ref} />;
}
```

Specifically, I'm referring to the use of `null!`.

Without the null-forgiving operator, we'd need to do a check like

```
if (ref.current) {
   // ... use ref.current
}
```

each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the following be considered bad practice?
>
> ```
> const Component: React.FC<{}> = () => {
>     const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null!);
>     
>     return <div ref={ref} />;
> }
> ```

Pretty much. It's not doing anything good for you, and it's potentially masking a `null` access later on – notably, while the component is being unmounted.

Suppose we added an (unwisely coded) effect to the component, with a cleanup callback:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
    return () => ref.current.blur();
});
```

When the effect cleanup is run, `ref.current` will be null. Typescript would normally detect this and report `'ref.current' is possibly null`, but by initialising the ref with `null!` we've asserted (falsely) that `ref.current` is never null. So, instead of detecting the problem during coding, we get a runtime error.